# error when writing to file after opening it with O_APPEND | O_CREATE

Tags: c, operating-system

I have opened a text file named "pranav" in O_APPEND | O_CREAT mode as shown below:

```
     #include<unistd.h>
     #include<fcntl.h>
     #include<stdio.h>
     main()
     {
     //FILE Descriptor fdes
     /*Open file pranav.txt in write-only mode,
      O_CREAT creates file if it does not exist*/
      int fdes = open("pranav.txt",O_APPEND | O_CREAT );
      //Error returns -1
      if(fdes!=-1)
      {
           //To write on file
             if((write(fdes,"Pranav",6))== -1)
             write(2,"File_Writing_Error",18);
             //To print on screen
             else
             write(1,"Done",4);
      }
      else
      {
            //Print "error" on screen
               write(2,"File_Opening_Error",18);
      }
      close(fdes);
       }
```

**In O_APPEND mode it executes the write(2,"File_Writing_Error",18); statement, thus not able to write "Pranav" on file, but this error does not occur and program successfully runs if I use O_WRONLY mode**

Comment: use `perror` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror) to print the real error message

Comment: use `perror()` function to know error

Comment: Thank you for increasing my knowlege. It printed the error: "Bad File Descriptor"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Documentation for `open` says, that you must give exactly one of the flags `O_RDONLY`, `O_WRONLY` and `O_RDWR` and that you can use any combination of the other flags like `O_APPEND` and `O_CREAT`.

You did not provide `O_WRONLY` in addition to `O_APPEND` and `O_CREAT`. My guess is that `O_RDONLY` is 0, so when not giving one of the access flags you end up with `O_RDONLY` and thus cannot write to the file.

So the correct code should be:

```
mode_t mode = S_IRWXU | SIRWXG;  // or any other mode
int fdes = open("pranav.txt", O_APPEND | O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, mode);
```

Please note the additional parameter `mode` which is required if the flags included `O_CREAT` or `O_TMPFILE`.

Comment: Thanx a lot. I used to think O_APPEND was a substitute for O_WRONLY, now I know that its to be used in conjunction with O_WRONLY